# No tag exists, and I'd like to get a feel for what tag should be used

Tags: discussion, tags

I still use a lot of Classic ASP/VBScript - migration is not an option at this point - and I find myself in need of a little code review. This leads to two problems:

1. I don't have enough rep to create a tag for Classic ASP and/or VBScript.
2. It would probably be a good idea to have a discussion now over what the correct tag would be so we don't [run into the problem I noticed on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/classic-re-tag-discussion-on-some-good-ole-asp-classic). There are several ways people tend to refer to the old ASP, and I'd rather resolve which is the "correct" way now.

Which one of these (or something I didn't even think of) should we be using? (And can someone create the tag so I can use it?)

- [asp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp) - by itself it is too ambiguous (it's used for both ASP 3.0 and ASP.NET)
- [asp-classic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) or [classic-asp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classic-asp) - more accurate, and more often used (former would probably be better)
- [asp3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp3) (or some variant) - probably more technically accurate, but less commonly used
- [asp-vbscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-vbscript) - most accurate, probably the most useful.

Answer (score 6):

[asp-classic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) seems to be the most popular on Stack Overflow for this.  I'd suggest we go with the same.  I'll add it if everyone agrees, or if someone gets to it before me, that's fine.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Would it be worth adding the VBScript tag as well to differentiate? I know that it tends to be assumed, but it's not necessarily a given.

Comment: @AnonJr: Sounds reasonable.  Go ahead and just ask your question on the main site and say what you want it tagged as.  Someone will do it and we can fix it if we need to later.

Comment: will do as soon as I finish asking why the first discussion over at the main Meta is MIA.